# Show text on top of the tick in the ruler

Tags: html, css

The code is provided in the fiddle link below.

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/thirdender/kwcug/)

**Code:**

```js
$(function() {
    // Build "dynamic" rulers by adding items
    $(".ruler[data-items]").each(function() {
        var ruler = $(this).empty(),
            len = Number(ruler.attr("data-items")) || 0,
            item = $(document.createElement("li")),
            i;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            ruler.append(item.clone().text(i + 1));
        }
    });
    // Change the spacing programatically
    function changeRulerSpacing(spacing) {
        $(".ruler").
          css("padding-right", spacing).
          find("li").
            css("padding-left", spacing);
    }
    $("#spacing").change(function() {
        changeRulerSpacing($(this).val());
    });
});
```

```css
.ruler, .ruler li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
/* IE6-7 Fix */
.ruler, .ruler li {
    *display: inline;
}
.ruler {
    background: lightYellow;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 1em hsl(60, 60%, 84%) inset;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #ccc;
    margin: 0;
    height: 3em;
    padding-right: 1cm;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.ruler li {
    padding-left: 1cm;
    width: 2em;
    margin: .64em -1em -.64em;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px hsl(60, 60%, 84%);
}
.ruler li:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: .64em;
    top: -.64em;
    right: 1em;
}

/* Make me pretty! */
body {
    font: 12px Ubuntu, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 20px;
}

div {
    margin-top: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ruler"><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li></ul>

<div>
    <ul class="ruler" data-items="10"></ul>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="spacing">Spacing</label>
    <select id="spacing">
        <option>1cm</option>
        <option>2cm</option>
        <option>1in</option>
        <option>1em</option>
        <option>20px</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

How can I show the text on top, next to the `li` tick in the provided link?

Currently, I am adding `vertical-align:top` to the css `.ruler li` but nothing changes in the UI.

Please check the image below. The requirement is shown in blue.

[image]

What css property in what css class do I need to add to make sure the text is shown at top and next to the tick?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're trying to achieve here? An image would be best

Comment: which text are you referring ?

Comment: @dippas.. I am referring to the numbers below the line. I need them at top and next to the line on right side.

Comment: @TheGaME they look to me like that using FF

Comment: Code in your question first. jsFiddle second

Answer (score 1):

Simply move the list items slightly to the right and up. Then move the `:before` pseudo elements the same amount to the left and down.

http://jsfiddle.net/kwcug/1006/

And I'm not sure why my update causes JSFiddle to think this one now has 1006 revisions.

Answer (score 1):

Add some left `position` to your `ruler li` and adjust your right `position` in `li:before`

```js
$(function() {
  // Build "dynamic" rulers by adding items
  $(".ruler[data-items]").each(function() {
    var ruler = $(this).empty(),
      len = Number(ruler.attr("data-items")) || 0,
      item = $(document.createElement("li")),
      i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      ruler.append(item.clone().text(i + 1));
    }
  });
  // Change the spacing programatically
  function changeRulerSpacing(spacing) {
    $(".ruler").
    css("padding-right", spacing).
    find("li").
    css("padding-left", spacing);
  }
  $("#spacing").change(function() {
    changeRulerSpacing($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```css
.ruler,
.ruler li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
/* IE6-7 Fix */

.ruler,
.ruler li {
  *display: inline;
}
.ruler {
  background: lightYellow;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 1em hsl(60, 60%, 84%) inset;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #ccc;
  margin: 0;
  height: 3em;
  padding-right: 1cm;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.ruler li {
  padding-left: 1cm;
  width: 2em;
  margin: .64em -1em -.64em;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px hsl(60, 60%, 84%);
  top: -.64em;
  left: .64em
}
.ruler li:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: .64em;
  right: 1.4em;
}
/* Make me pretty! */

body {
  font: 12px Ubuntu, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 20px;
}
div {
  margin-top: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" src="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" />
<ul class="ruler">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>

<div>
  <ul class="ruler" data-items="10"></ul>
</div>

<div>
  <label for="spacing">Spacing</label>
  <select id="spacing">
    <option>1cm</option>
    <option>2cm</option>
    <option>1in</option>
    <option>1em</option>
    <option>20px</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

http://jsfiddle.net/kwcug/1008/

I changed this

```
.ruler li {
    margin: .64em -1em -.64em;
}
.ruler li:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: .64em;
    top: -.64em;
    right: 1em;
}
```

to

```
.ruler li:before {
    content: '';
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-right: .2em;
}
.ruler li {
    margin: 0 -1em -.64em;
}
```